# Double Mediation?

Tags: r, factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, mediation, lavaan

[image]Can anyone help me with what this `lavaan` (R  package) syntax is doing? I got a question: Is it correct that a kind of nested multiple mediation is tested with this code:

```
(X = "predictor", XM1 = "predictor 2" in "mediation 2" and "mediator 1" in "mediation 1", M2 = "mediator 2", Y = "criterion")
```

Which codes the following paths:

- `indirect1` being the indirect effect of $X -> XM_1 -> Y$
- `indirect2` being the indirect effect of $XM_1 -> M_2 -> Y$
- `total` being the total effect of $X -> XM_1 -> Y$
- `total1` being the total effect of $XM_1 -> M_2 -> Y$
- `total2` being the total effect of $X -> XM_1 -> M_2 -> Y$

Is a term missing? Such as "`indirect3 := a1 + a2`"

## Model Syntax From Lavaan

```
Y ~ b1 * XM1 + b2 * M2 + c * X

pmc ~ a1 * X

indirect1 := a1 * b1

indirect2 := b2 + b1

total := c + (a1 * b1)

total1 := b1 + (a2 * b2)

total2 := c + (a1 * b2) + (a1 * a2 * b2)

M2 ~ a2 * XM1
```